# Unresolved symbols: linking against static libraries included from other cmake packages

Tags: c++, build, cmake, static, symbols

I am struggling with building a CMake package, which uses one *external* static library included from another CMake packages. I prepared a crude diagram for you to visualize my set-up. Marked with purple are CMake packages.

[image]

I am able to compile the package *lib* and *framework* individually without any problems what so ever. 
However when I try to build *exe*, using *lib* and *framework* the linker tells me that it can not resolve the symbols coming from the external library (python37).

**EDIT #3:**

```
framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyType_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyType_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyType_Type
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyBaseObject_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyBaseObject_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyBaseObject_Type
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_NoneStruct
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_NoneStruct
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_NoneStruct
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_NotImplementedStruct
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_NotImplementedStruct
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_NotImplementedStruct
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_FalseStruct
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_FalseStruct
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_FalseStruct
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_TrueStruct
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_TrueStruct
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Py_TrueStruct
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyCFunction_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyCFunction_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyCFunction_Type
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInstanceMethod_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInstanceMethod_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInstanceMethod_Type
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyCapsule_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyCapsule_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyCapsule_Type
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyProperty_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyProperty_Type
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyProperty_Type
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_ImportError
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_IndexError
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_IndexError
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_IndexError
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_MemoryError
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_MemoryError
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_MemoryError
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_OverflowError
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_OverflowError
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_OverflowError
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_RuntimeError
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_RuntimeError
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_RuntimeError
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_SystemError
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_SystemError
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_SystemError
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_TypeError
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_TypeError
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_TypeError
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_ValueError
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_ValueError
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_ValueError
4>framework.lib(DebugCommunicationLink.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_FutureWarning
4>lib.lib(PythonModuleLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_FutureWarning
4>lib.lib(PythonScriptingSystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyExc_FutureWarning
4>D:\Code\Cplusplus\SupraHotSandbox\vsstudio\Debug\suprahotsandbox.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
```

I also tried generating the *exe* project for Visual Studio and set the linker inputs manually to the external library (python37.lib), without any success.

**My question is:** What is the best way to solve this?

**And secondly, although not as important:** Is there an approach, which will work cross-platform, to bundle all dependencies into one single 'master' static library?

Here are the downsized versions of the CMakeLists I created.

Thank you in advance.

**CMakeLists.txt for "lib"**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(lib)

SET (LIB_FOLDER "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
SET (LIB_VENDOR_FOLDER  "${LIB_FOLDER}/vendor")
SET (LIB_SOURCE_FOLDER "${LIB_FOLDER}/source")

# external lib
add_library(
    python-3-7-7
    STATIC IMPORTED
)
set_property(TARGET python-3-7-7 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "CORRECT_PATH_TO_LIB/python-3-7-7.lib")

add_library(
    lib
    STATIC
    # list of source files
    # ......
)

#includes
target_include_directories(
    lib
    PRIVATE ${LIB_FOLDER} 
    PRIVATE ${LIB_VENDOR_FOLDER} 
    # ......
)
# linkage
target_link_libraries(lib python-3-7-7)
```

**CMakeLists.txt for "framework"**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(framework)

SET (FRAMEWORK_FOLDER "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
SET (FRAMEWORK_SOURCE "${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER}/source")
SET (FRAMEWORK_VENDOR_FOLDER  "${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER}/vendor")

# -------------- OPEN GL ---------------------
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
# -------------- OPEN GL ---------------------

# ---------------GLEW START-------------------
# glew-2.1.0
SET (GLEW_FOLDER  "${FRAMEWORK_VENDOR_FOLDER}/glew-2.1.0")
SET (GLEW_INCLUDE_FOLDER  "${GLEW_FOLDER}/include")
SET (GLEW_SOURCE_FOLDER  "${GLEW_FOLDER}/src")

add_library(
    glew32s 
    ${GLEW_SOURCE_FOLDER}/glew.c
)
target_compile_definitions(glew32s PRIVATE GLEW_STATIC)
target_include_directories(glew32s PRIVATE ${GLEW_INCLUDE_FOLDER})
# ---------------GLEW END--------------------

# ---------------GLFW START-------------------
# glfw-3.3
SET(GLFW_FOLDER "${FRAMEWORK_VENDOR_FOLDER}/glfw-3.3")
SET(GLFW_INCLUDE_FOLDER "${GLFW_FOLDER}/include")
add_subdirectory(${GLFW_FOLDER})
# ---------------GLFW END-------------------

# ---------------LIB START-------------------
add_subdirectory(${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER}/lib)
# ---------------LIB END---------------------

# ---------------FRAMEWORK START-------------------
add_library(
    framework

    # source
    ${FRAMEWORK_SOURCE}/App.cpp
    # .....

    # headers
    ${FRAMEWORK_SOURCE}/App.h
    # .....
)

target_compile_definitions(
   framework 
   PRIVATE GLEW_STATIC
)

target_include_directories(
    framework
    PRIVATE ${FRAMEWORK_SOURCE} 
    PRIVATE ${GLEW_INCLUDE_FOLDER}
    PRIVATE ${GLFW_INCLUDE_FOLDER}
   # ....
)

target_link_libraries(
    framework 
    PUBLIC lib
    PUBLIC glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} 
    PUBLIC glew32s 
    PUBLIC ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}
)
# ---------------FRAMEWORK END-------------------
```

**CMakeLists.txt for "exe"**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(sandbox)

SET (SANDBOX_FOLDER "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
SET (SANDBOX_SOURCE "${SANDBOX_FOLDER}/source")

add_subdirectory(${SANDBOX_FOLDER}/framework)

# ------------ SANDBOX START -------------
add_executable(
    sandbox
    ${SANDBOX_SOURCE}/Bootstrap.cpp
    ${SANDBOX_SOURCE}/FrameworkApp.cpp

    # headers
    ${SANDBOX_SOURCE}/FrameworkApp.h
)

target_link_libraries(
    sandbox
    framework # also tried just linking against this and remove the ones below
    lib
    glew32s
    glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
)

target_include_directories(
    sandbox
    PRIVATE ${SANDBOX_SOURCE}
    # ....
)

target_compile_definitions(sandbox PRIVATE GLEW_STATIC)
# ------------ SANDBOX END ---------------
```

Comment: "when I try to build exe, using lib and framework the linker tells me that it can not resolve some symbols." - Please, add **exact error message** to the question post. This message should include, among other things, which file is linked and which file misses the symbols.

Comment: I updated the post to make things clearer. Thanks for pointing that out. It looks to me that the linker can not find the symbols coming from the external library I mentioned in the post

Comment: The error message clearly points to your `lib` and `framework` libraries. It seems you didn't link these libraries with the one which provides missed symbols. "I am able to compile the package lib and framework individually without any problems what so ever." - Building a **static** library doesn't perform **linking** stage, which emits "unresolved external symbol" errors. Change these libraries to `SHARED` and you will face the same errors when build these libraries.

Comment: you were right. setting it to SHARED helped a lot figuring what was going on. turns out I had a #define somewhere in the header I forgot I put there. I can compile, link and run the program. thanks!